# How can I add X-Frame-Options selectively using Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, x-frame-options

I am planning to set `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` in my server's `httpd.conf` as part of improving the defenses against click jacking. I understand this will add the `X-Frame-Options` header to *all* pages. There is a "widget" page that I would like to exempt from this (other sites will display this page inside an `IFRAME`).

Is there a way to configure Apache 2 to not send the header for a specific page alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `SetEnvIf`:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/my_awesome_widget_page.html$" iframes_are_cool
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN env=!iframes_are_cool
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unset the X-Frame-Options header in a .htaccess file (assuming your widget is in its own subdirectory):

```
Header always unset X-Frame-Options
```